# OTP authentication problem with FIREBASE and vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Hello I'm working on an application made in vuejs and firebase and I use OTP authentication for account creation. I got to do this. When the phone number field and the verification code field are on the same page, the authentication passes and I am redirected to the next page.
Now I decided to separate the two fields (phone number and verification code) by creating a page to enter the phone number and a second page to enter the verification code. Unfortunately this does not work, the code verification page does not recognize the code entered.
please help me.

Page 1: (Login.vue)

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" style="background-color:#34B76E;">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7">
    <b-container>
      <b-row class="vh-100" align-v="center">
        <div>
          <b-card no-body class="" style="max-width: 540px; background-color:#EFF3F8; 
            border-radius:20px 20px 20px 20px;">
            <b-row no-gutters class="" style="">

              <b-col md="5" style="background:#FFAB0E; width:200px; border-radius:20px 0px 
                0px 20px;">                    
                <!--
                <img src="../../assets/images/bg.png" height="300" width="170">
                <b-card-img src="https://picsum.photos/400/400/?image=20" alt="Image" 
                  class="rounded-0"></b-card-img>
                 -->
              </b-col>
              
              <b-col md="7">
                <b-card-body>
                  <h2 style="color:black; font-weight:bold">Backoffice</h2>
                  <span style="font-size:0.8em; color:gray">Veuillez-vous connecter à votre 
      compte</span>
                  <div style="height:40px"></div>
                  <b-card-text style="">
                    <div style="width:250px;">
                        <b-form>
                          <b-form-text>
                            Indiquez votre numéro de téléphone
                          </b-form-text>
                          <b-form-group>
                            <b-form-input type="text" v-model="phone" aria-describedby="tel" 
       placeholder="+225 00 07 05 01 00" required style="border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px; 
       text-align:center"></b-form-input>
                          </b-form-group>
                            <b-button id="sign-in-button" @click="sendCode" block 
       variant="success active" style="border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                              Continuer
                            </b-button>
                          <div id="recaptcha-container"></div><br>
                        </b-form>

                    </div>
                  </b-card-text>
                  
                  <div style="height:40px"></div>
                  <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-12 text-right">

                      <router-link to="/LoginCompte" class="text-light">
                        <small style="color:gray">Login Compte</small>
                      </router-link> <br>
                      <router-link to="/verify" class="text-light">
                        <small style="color:gray">Verify</small>
                      </router-link>
                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </b-card-body>
              </b-col>

            </b-row>
          </b-card>
        </div>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
    </div>
    </div>

    </template>

 <script> 
  import firebase from "firebase";

   export default {
    name: 'login',
 data(){
  return{
    phone: '',
    appVerifier : '',
  }
},
  methods :{
  sendCode(){
    if(this.phone.length != 10){
      alert('Numero invalide !');
      }else{
      //
      let countryCode = '+225' //civ
      let phoneNumber = countryCode + this.phone
      let nextpage = this
      //
      let appVerifier = this.appVerifier
      //
      firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function (confirmationResult) 
        {
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
          //
          //alert('Continuer')
          nextpage.$router.push({path:'/Verify'})
        }).catch(function (error) {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // ...
        alert('Erreur, code non envoyer')
      });
    }
  },
  // 
   
   //
  verifyCode(){
    if(this.phone.length != 10 || this.otpCode.length != 6){
      alert('Numero ou Format invalide !');
    }else{
      //
      let vm = this
      let code = this.otpCode
      //
      window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
        // User signed in successfully.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
        //route to set password !
        vm.$router.push({path:'./LoginCompte'})
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
        // ...
      });
    }
  },

  initReCaptcha(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let vm = this
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', 
        {
         'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': function(response) 
        {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          // ...
        },
        'expired-callback': function() 
        {
          // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
          // ...
        }
      });
      //
      this.appVerifier =  window.recaptchaVerifier
    },1000)
  }
},
created(){
  this.initReCaptcha()
}
}
</script>


<style>
</style>
```

Page 2: (Verify.vue)

```
   <template>

 <div class="row justify-content-center" style="background-color:#34B76E;">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7">
    <b-container>
      <b-row class="vh-100" align-v="center">
        <div>
          <b-card no-body class="" style="max-width: 540px; background-color:#EFF3F8; 
         border-radius:20px 20px 20px 20px;">
            <b-row no-gutters class="" style="">

              <b-col md="5" style="background:#FFAB0E; width:200px; border-radius:20px 0px 
        0px 20px;">                    
                
              </b-col>
              
              <b-col md="7">
                <b-card-body>
                  <h2 style="color:black; font-weight:bold">Backoffice</h2>
                  <span style="font-size:0.8em; color:gray">Veuillez-vous connecter à votre 
          compte</span>
                  <div style="height:40px"></div>
                  <b-card-text style="">
                    <div style="width:250px;">
                       
                        <b-form hidden>
                          <b-form-text id="tel">
                            Indiquez votre numéro de téléphone
                          </b-form-text>
                          <b-input-group class="mt-3">
                            <b-form-input type="text" v-model="phone" id="tel" aria- 
          describedby="tel" placeholder="00 07 05 01 00" required style="border-radius:10px 
      0px 0px 10px; text-align:center"></b-form-input>
                            <b-input-group-append>
                              <b-button id="sign-in-button" @click="sendCode" block 
            variant="success active" style="height:40px; border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0px;">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
                              </b-button>
                            </b-input-group-append>
                          </b-input-group>
                          <div id="recaptcha-container"></div><br>
                        </b-form>
                      

                        <div>
                          <b-form>
                            <b-form-text id="tel">
                              Veuillez indiquer le code reçu par SMS
                            </b-form-text>
                            <b-form-group>
                              <b-form-input type="text" v-model="otpCode" aria- 
        describedby="tel" placeholder="00 00 00" required style="border-radius:10px 10px 
       10px 10px; text-align:center"></b-form-input>
                            </b-form-group>
                            <b-button  @click="verifyCode" block variant="success active" 
            style="border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;">Se connecter</b-button>
                          </b-form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  </b-card-text>
                  
                  <div style="height:40px"></div>
                  <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-12 text-right">
                      <router-link to="/" class="text-light">
                        <small style="color:gray">Vous n'avez pas reçu de code?</small>
                      </router-link>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </b-card-body>
              </b-col>

            </b-row>
          </b-card>
        </div>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
</div>
</div>

</template>

<script> 
import firebase from "firebase";

  export default {
 name: 'verify',
 data(){
  return{
    phone: '',
    appVerifier : '',
    otpCode : ''
  }
 },
 methods :{
  sendCode(){
    if(this.phone.length != 10){
      alert('Numero invalid !');
    }else{
      //
      let countryCode = '+225' //civ
      let phoneNumber = countryCode + this.phone
      //let nextpage = this
      //
      let appVerifier = this.appVerifier
      //
      firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function (confirmationResult) {
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
          //
          alert('Continuer')
          //nextpage.$router.push({path:'/Verify'})
        }).catch(function (error) {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // ...
        alert('Erreur, code non envoyer')
      });
    }
  },
  //
  verifyCode(){
    if(this.phone.length != 10 || this.otpCode.length != 6){
      alert('Numero ou Format invalide !');
    }else{
      //
      let vm = this
      let code = this.otpCode
      //
      window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
        // User signed in successfully.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
        //route to set password !
        vm.$router.push({path:'./LoginCompte'})
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
        // ...
      });
    }
  },
  
  initReCaptcha(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let vm = this
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', 
        {
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': function(response) {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          // ...
        },
        'expired-callback': function() {
          // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
          // ...
        }
      });
      //
      this.appVerifier =  window.recaptchaVerifier
    },1000)
  }
 },
 created(){
  this.initReCaptcha()
 }
 }
 </script>


 <style>
 </style>
```